# Selective file sharing between windows and osx machine

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing

I have several external hard disk drives attached to a windows machine and I would like to share them with my macbook. I would like to restrict the access to those shares using a username and password. Is there an easy way to set this up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure they are formatted correctly. OSX doesn't read ntfs so format it as FAT32.

Next make sure the firewalls are configured correctly on both sides.  SMB uses 445, along with 137-139.  OSX has a check box. Windows also automatically configures the firewall when you turn on the following in Network Center: Network discovery ON, File Sharing with Password ON.  If you want, you can share public folders.

Make sure you have a username and password that matches on each computer. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is assign permissions to your shared folders.

That is, on the Windows system, you have to right click on a folder you want to share, and there, under security, you can modify what users have what rights when accessing that folder.

Now, the easiest way to manage Windows shares on a MAC is simply mapping the network drives permanently with the different usernames. This way you don't have to deal with the hassle of typing in usernames and passwords every time.

Remember that when entering the password you should include the host computer name before the username, that is:

[hostComputer]\[userWithAccess]

That way you won't run into any unecessary issues with the authentication.